# Boost: is_any_of generates multiple errors

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, trim

I just installed boost and all functions that i used so far has worked fine, but when i used trim_if when you need to use boost::is_any_of it generated multiple errors.

**This is some of the errors i'm getting:**

```
error C2868: 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>::iterator_category' : illegal syntax
for using-declaration; expected qualified-name
```

---

```
error C2825: '_Iter': must be a class or namespace when 
followed by '::'
```

---

```
error C2602: 'boost::range_iterator<C>::type' is not a member of a base class 
of 'boost::range_iterator<C>'
```

---

```
error C2602: 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>::iterator_category' 
is not a member of a base class of 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>'
```

---

```
error C2039: 'iterator_category' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
```

I have tried to reinstall boost but that didn't work.

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string string = "\t\tthis is a string\t";

    boost::trim_if(string, boost::is_any_of('\t'));

    std::cout << string << std::cout;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in the call `boost::is_any_of('\t')`.

`is_any_of` takes a sequence of characters, and you are passing a single character.

Change your code to:

```
     boost::trim_if(string, boost::is_any_of("\t"));
```

i.e, use double-quoes instead of single quotes.